# Implementing infinite scroll on top when scrolling using library (I have live code sample)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement with the help of this library [react-infinite-scroll-component](https://github.com/ankeetmaini/react-infinite-scroll-component)  (documentation)
to do an infite scroll, my idea is to have the infinite scroll at the top.

I am using the live [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/w3w89k7x8?file=/src/index.js)(code sample) provided by this library, but I am unable to implement the infinite scroll at the top, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

In the library they mention this to achieve this:

**Using scroll on top**

```
    <div
    id="scrollableDiv"
    style={{
        height: 300,
        overflow: 'auto',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column-reverse',
    }}
    >
    {/*Put the scroll bar always on the bottom*/}
    <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={this.state.items.length}
        next={this.fetchMoreData}
        style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column-reverse' }} //To put endMessage and loader to the top.
        inverse={true} //
        hasMore={true}
        loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
        scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
    >
        {this.state.items.map((_, index) => (
        <div style={style} key={index}>
            div - #{index}
        </div>
        ))}
    </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
```

I try to replace it but it doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: when the scroll is top you want load new data am i right ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below code and check if it works for your query.

```
 <InfiniteScroll
    dataLength={this.state.items.length + Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 1}
     next={this.fetchMoreData}
     style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column-reverse' }}
     hasMore={this.state.hasMore}
     loader={
       <div className="loading">
         Loading ...
       </div>
     }
     height={'calc(100vh - 10px)'}
     endMessage={<span />}
     refreshFunction={this.fetchMoreData}
     pullDownToRefresh={true}
     pullDownToRefreshContent={
       <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Circle SVG/img</div>
     }
     releaseToRefreshContent={
       <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Circle SVG/img</div>
     }
      >
       {
         this.state.items.map((_, index) => (
          <div style={style} key={index}>
            div - #{index}
          </div>
        ))
      }             
</InfiniteScroll>
```

Comment: can you share this code in a live sample? currently it is not working for me..

Comment: I create this live code with this piece of code: https://codesandbox.io/s/yk7637p62z?file=/src/index.js I add some details in the question

Comment: @yavgz i have added the code https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-mclean-fkq3x?file=/src/index.js , if you pull it down you can see 'Circle/SVG image' replace that with some animated svg loader

Comment: Thanks genious!  I am very grateful, there is one detail that I have not managed to do. How can I make that when I scroll from the beginning of the div (in addition to the pull) the infinite scroll works?

Comment: @yavgz `refreshFunction={this.fetchMoreData}` you have this `refreshFunction` where you can add your api call function and the result you can store in your usestate/redux state.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code it's working !

```
<div id="scrollableDiv" style={{
          height: 300,
          overflow: "auto",
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column-reverse"
        }}>
          <InfiniteScroll
            dataLength={this.state.items.length}
            next={this.fetchMoreData}
            style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column-reverse' }} //To put endMessage and loader to the top.
            inverse={true} //
            hasMore={true}
            loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
            scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv"
            // below props only if you need pull down functionality
            refreshFunction={this.fetchMoreData}
            pullDownToRefresh
            pullDownToRefreshThreshold={50}
            pullDownToRefreshContent={
              <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>&#8595;</h3>
            }
            releaseToRefreshContent={
              <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>&#8593;</h3>
            }
          >
            {this.state.items.map((_, index) => (
              <div style={style} key={index}>
                div - #{index}
              </div>
            ))}
          </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
```

Comment: I create this live code with this piece of code: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-grass-c024v I add some details in the question